# Appscale install failed

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, appscale

What could be the cause of this error when running *bootstrap.sh*

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.4.0/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_conntrack not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 262144
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_orphan_retries: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_orphans: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range: No such file or directory
failed!
```

Comment: What OS are you using? And did you custom built your kernel? It seems you are missing some basic modules, or perhaps you did upgraded your kernel and you haven't rebooted yet? If you have still trouble please file a ticker with AppScale, or find us on the google group.

Comment: Actually we use Docker inside Jelastic (see: https://docs.jelastic.com/dockers-overview)

Comment: I'm not familiar with jelastic: usual docker running on Ubuntu or Linux seems to do fine. Can you make sure you are using the latest 3.5? Also you can try to add an exit 0 at the second line in the firewall.conf (you will find it in /root/appscale).